# How to get currency of a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, currency

I need help to handle the following situation:
I have some values that I need to sum in a page, but the fields of these values are created dynamically (so are the ids of these fields).

The values can be displayed in different format (depending on the currency or decimal places), i.e.: R$20.000,2 (1 decimal place) or US$20.000,18 (2 decimal places) or €20,000.180 (3 decimal places and imperial system).

**What did I do until now:**

Since the fields are created dynamically, I added a css class to the style of that fields (they're generated through a for each loop), then I use a javascript prototype class that I created to convert string to float (if I pass R$20.000,02 or R$20,000.02 and it returns 20000.02). the following code iterates in all fields generated in the page that I need to sum.

```
<script>
    var sum = 0;
    jQuery(".countTotalEffectiveMonth").each(function(){
        sum += localeUtils.s2f(jQuery(this).text().replace("R$",""));
        jQuery("#ScenarioCurrentYearSavings").text(sum);

        })
    alert(sum);

</script>
```

**The problem:**

**1:** I hardcoded the currency ("R$","") (to remove it from the string and make calculation). any ideas about how can I do that?
I tried to use regex, but I failed :(. I could only remove the currency using this regex (/[^0-9-]/g), but I didn't know how to store it so that I could concatenate it in the end of the sum.

**UPDATE:**

By following Paul S.'s approach, I did this:

```
var val;
var re = /^([a-z]+)([^\d])([\d.,]+)$/i;
var m;
jQuery(".countTotalEffectiveMonth").each(function(){
    m = jQuery(this).text();
    val = re.exec(m);
    val += val[3].replace(/,/g, '');
    alert(val[1]+val[3]);
    jQuery("#ScenarioCurrentYearSavings").text(val[1]+val[3]);

});
```

It says that val is null, but I printed m just before executing `val = re.exec(m);` and it prints a number like this **R$91,67**, but them I receive TypeError: val is null.

Can you see what is wrong?

Comment: do you have different currency symbols hardcoded or only R$?

Comment: Assuming I am understanding you correctly, you can just store the currency in a var and append it to the end or the beginning of your result so var + sum or sum + var

Comment: I have no hardcoded symbols, @kasperTaeymans (they're all generated according to the user locale... I hardcoded it in my javascript function to make a test if it would work (it did! :) ). but I was trying to find a way to get this stored via javascript, I'm also trying to send it directly from the user object, but it's not being easy to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a regexp that looks like this

```
var re = /^([a-z]+)([^\d])([\d.,]+)$/i,
    m;
m = re.exec('US$20.000,18'); // ["US$20.000,18", "US", "$", "20.000,18"]
m = re.exec('R$20,000.02');  // [ "R$20,000.02",  "R", "$", "20,000.02"]
```

Then `m[3]` is the numeric value, and this can be converted to a *Number* using more logic, e.g. if it's in the form `x,xxx.xx`

```
var int = +m[3].replace(/,/g, ''); // 20000.02
```

Comment: Will it work for €, since it won't have the $ symbol?

Comment: `re.exec('EU€1.50'); // ["EU€1.50", "EU", "€", "1.50"]`, it's just matching a non-digit there.

Comment: there isn't an EU before the euro symbol.. :/ (I also wasn't able to use this exec function... I mean.. I'll update the question so u can see what I'm doing now (following your approach), but it isn't working

Comment: If the letters on the front are optional then change `+` to `*`, i.e. `[a-z]*`